# how to display the list of corresponding users by using user reference module

Tags: 7, views, users

I have 3 user role that

Senior->users(senior1,senior2)

Sub_Senior->users(subsenior1,subsenior2)

junior->users(j1,j2,j3,j4)

the user subsenior1 is belonging to senior2 , user subsenior2 is belonging to senior1.

the users j1,j2 belonging to subsenior1 and users j3,j4 belonging to subsenior2 referenced by using user reference fields

but i am not able to list the corresponding users in views page like when i click the senior1 user it will list the corresponding subsenior2 user(corresponding all referenced users).

I'm extremely new to drupal any one help me ..

thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you heard about [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views)? Also, in Drupal 7 [Entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) seems to be a better (more universal) way than D6 *something*-reference series of modules.